# Ubuntu One intermittent sync

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have found that Ubuntu One sometimes will sync a local file to the Ubuntu One website, and other times it will not.

How can I debug this?

I'm sitting at my machine making edits and saving several files, all of which are in folders that are to be Ubuntu-One sync'd.  When I look at the website (even much later, say, the next day) only some of the files were sync'd.

Any ideas?

EDIT 1:  I'll add this:  I only see this problem with folders other than the Ubuntu One folder. The Ubuntu One folder seems to always stay in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've the same problem. Third party services like Dropbox seem to be more reliable. Restarting Ubuntu One service may help:

```
u1sdtool --quit
u1sdtool --connect
u1sdtool --refresh-shares
u1sdtool --status
u1sdtool --current-transfers
```

For debugging purposes logfiles are located at: ~/.cache/ubuntuone/log. I think they're a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks chris.  I've had limited success with u1sdtool --quit and --start, but haven't tried the others.  In any case, I'm moving to using the Ubuntu One folder only for now.  I also have Dropbox and have never had any problems with it--although I only use its Dropbox folder.

Comment: Well I've given up on Ubuntu One and have moved to Dropbox which works flawlessly.